# The API query failed with status code BadRequest:

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to hit an asp.net Web API to get result from database which used internally EF code.

Most of the time, I'm getting result, but sometime, the process taking more time (execute EF code and/or getting data from DB) and I'm getting below error,

`The API query failed with status code BadRequest:`

Could someone please suggest what this mean and how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like your service throws an internal error, e.g. timeout during the DB query. You have to look at the log file of your service to see what is really going on. It is hard to tell you more without the stack trace of the internal exception.

Comment: Yes, it's a timeout only, how to fix it?

Comment: Quick fix would be to [increase the timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) on the DB server. Clean fix would be to use the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) to find out why the query is taking so long (are you missing an index?).